# iOS - Auto Constraints on Programmatically Added View

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to programmatically added a UIPageViewController under a custom page control at the top of the screen, but filling out the rest of the screen. What I have works when the page initially loads, but when the device rotates, it does not readjust its size to fill just the screen (i.e., the constraints only work on the initial load). What am I missing here?

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResultsPageView") as? UIPageViewController

    self.loadActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.topPageControl.hidden = true

    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = CGRectZero

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

    self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topPageControl, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let constraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let constraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let constraintTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraint(constraintTop)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraintBottom)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraintLeading)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraintTrailing)
    self.pageViewController!.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this code doesn't work, but since your pageViewController is in the storyboard, why not add a container view in the storyboard, and set up its constraints there. Delete the view controller you automatically get with the container view, and connect your pageViewController to it instead.

Comment: That does seem like a smarter way to go about it. Still, I'm curious why this isn't properly resizing on rotate.

Comment: I doubt this will make any difference, but you shouldn't need to set the pageViewController's view frame to CGRectZero. Try removing that line, and see if that fixes it.